# std::map fails to insert objects

Tags: c++, stdmap, static-classes

A program I'm making requires access pools of various types of resources, but only accessible to a few classes. The resource pool is also its own class. As such, I decided to use a static class for the resource pool and have others access it this way.

But I am running into a strange problem with adding resources to the pool. Each pool is represented as an std::map, and after insertion, the map still remains empty. I am guessing this has something to do with the map being inside a static class. Is this why maps don't work as intended here?

Relevant code of Resource Pool

```
class ResourcePool {

 private:
        static ResourcePool m_ResourcePool;

 public:
        ResourcePool();
        ~ResourcePool();
        static ResourcePool* Instance() { return &m_ResourcePool; }
  // Where textures are stored. ci_less is for case comparison of names
  std::map <std::string, TextureResource, ci_less> Textures;

  TextureResource* getTexture(std::string handle);
};
```

Relevant code of how it's used

```
Scene::Scene() {

 Assets = ResourcePool::Instance();
}

TextureResource* Scene::add(std::string handle, TextureResource Texture) {

 // Insertion fails
 Assets->Textures.insert(std::make_pair(handle + "_tex", Texture));

 // I use this line to debug, the map still shows up empty
 unsigned size = Assets->Textures.size();

 // look up that texture by its name
 return Assets->getTexture(handle);
}
```

The result is, add returns NULL since nothing is found. This program doesn't crash since I'm not doing anything with the texture, just testing out the insertion for now.

Comment: If this: `static ResourcePool* Instance()` never returns NULL then make it return a reference.

Comment: Assets->Textures[handle + "_tex"] = Texture; ?

Comment: Need to see the code foe `ci_less`. It would be a lot simpler if you wrote a small compilable application that runs and demonstrates the problem. Without it is just educated guesses. And the processes of building the example will probably lead you to the answer anyway.

Comment: `Assets->Textures()` : would there happen to be a `Texture` member function which you don't show but return the `map` by copy ?

Comment: Martin York, I removed the ci_less functionality from the map (which was surprisingly easy to do) and debugged again with the new format. Same problems with the insertion.

Comment: icecrime, oops that was a mistake. It was supposed to be the public member, not a member function. I corrected the code.

Comment: Why not just store the cache in the master render class?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't contain a proper compilable program, I have created one:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class ResourcePool {

 private:
        static ResourcePool m_ResourcePool;

 public:
        static ResourcePool* Instance() { return &m_ResourcePool; }
        std::map <std::string, std::string> Textures;
        std::string getTexture(std::string handle) { return Textures[handle]; }
};

ResourcePool ResourcePool::m_ResourcePool;

int main()
{
    ResourcePool* Assets = ResourcePool::Instance();
    Assets->Textures.insert(std::make_pair("test_tex", "texture"));
    std::cout << Assets->Textures.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Assets->getTexture("test_tex") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works on my machine as expected using linux, g++ Debian 4.3.2-1.1.
I wonder if it works for the original poster.